# Adding up Values of different Indexes automatically

Tags: python

I have a list (a), which contains references to another list (b). I am trying to create a third list (c), which contains the summed up values of (b) referenced in the according index of (a). Below is an example to hopefully make it clearer.

I have a rather large data set and this needs to be done frequently as part of an optimization process. Is there a way besides nested for-loops to do this efficiently and automated, without having to define every entry of c?

```
a = [[0],[0,3],[1,2],[3],[1,2,3]]
b = [10,20,30,40]
c = [b[0], b[0]+b[3], b[1]+b[2], b[3], b[1]+b[2]+b[3]]
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and sorry for potential mistakes in the post. It's my first and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you need it to be pure python only, but if not - you can use [numpy library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c = np.array(b)
>>> [sum(c[i]) for i in a]
[10, 50, 50, 40, 90]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a list comprehension: It takes the indices from each inner list in `a`, builds a list of the `b` values corresponding, sums them up, and stores them in a list that is assigned to `d`.

```
a = [[0], [0, 3], [1, 2], [3], [1, 2, 3]]
b = [10, 20, 30, 40]

d = [sum(b[idx] for idx in indices) for indices in a]
print(d)
```

#### output:

```
[10, 50, 50, 40, 90]
```

Comment: I was a bit too late to add pure python solution, so removed it from my answer to avoid duplication.
My guess would be that numpy will work faster for larger arrays, but it's only a guess

Comment: you can go one step further with numpy.  It accepts an array as a 'projection' of another array.

Comment: I agree with you gentlemen, although I doubt the OP wants a numpy solution at this stage.

Comment: true that, and in any case - it's always good to know pure python solution